# Access 2013 with many sub-reports -- System Resources error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

My database has 28 connected tables.  10 of those tables are used to create a Quote using a Multi-Tab Form. Once that is filled out, I have to print them onto a report. The report is broken down into many Sub Reports... 31-32 of them. The form then needs to be either Printed or Exported to a PDF.

I am running a PC with 16 Gig Ram and an 8 core CPU.

To set the RecordSource of the Main Report, I use the Following Code:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

  Dim dbs As Database
  Dim rstSQL As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strSQL As String

  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  strSQL = "SELECT fJobID FROM tblJobs GROUP BY fJobID " _
      & "HAVING (((fJobID)= " & [Forms]![frmHub2]![Combo0].[Value] & "));"

  Debug.Print strSQL

  Me.RecordSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

I had to use VBA to inject the value of `[Forms]![frmHub2]![Combo0].[Value]` into the SQL Definition.

### What Works

The form loads, I can choose previous jobs to update them, and I can VIEW the report in report view.

### What Doesn't

1. Once I try to go from Report View to Print Preview, I get a "System Resources Exceeded" Error.
2. When I open up directly into Print Preview mode, I can view it as it should, but I get the same error when trying to print, and it happens multiple times (Which makes me think it is occurring when processing the Sub Reports) and sometimes it will print a partial paper, and sometimes it does not print at all.

Any thoughts?

As usual, I will answer any questions, post any images, and do whatever I need to do to help understand the situation.

Comment: `Set dbs = CurrentDb` does not appear to contribute anything.  Wondering why it's there?

Comment: Your SQL doesn't seem to make sense as a RecordSource, because the resulting recordset would consist of one value, and that value would be equal to the value of `frmHub2!Combo0`.  I wonder what's going on...

Comment: The Set dbs = CurrentDb is there because I found this code, then I modified it to make it work. And Yes, the value of frmHub2!Combo0 IS a single value, but it is used as a filter. tblJobs is basically a list of all our jobs with information like the Name and Number of said Job, but the jobID is then used to filter information from the linked tables. I can try to explain more in a longer comment or other way if you need me to.

Comment: A data source for a report would typically require a record (or records) with multiple fields.  So `SELECT * FROM tblJobs` would seem possible, but `SELECT fJobID FROM tblJobs` not, because it returns one solitary value.  **AHA!**  Your report must be composed entirely of sub-reports.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a work-around is the best solution.  :-)

Instead of dozens of sub-reports, perhaps you can create multiple reports which are combined for the final result.  A bit of code will let you print them in succession, obviously.

---

Your *main* report is unbound, functionally:  it's not populated with a recordset.  The `ID` value serves as a variable to filter the sub-reports.  That's the best I can deduce -- looking forward to your insights.  If I'm correct, perhaps this observation will contribute to a sense of flexibility for revising this report.

Comment: That is correct, the Report is currently comprised of 32 Sub-Reports. I can email the DB to you if it would help, but I cannot post it online. And is there a medium other than this that you may prefer to diagnose an issue like this? Email, Skype, Logmein Rescue, whatever?

Comment: I can't diagnose this, but my Google research is summarized in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Several potential causes:

1. Remove all the code that you don't need.  Snippets are great, unless you don't understand what they do.  At least test every line and comment out everything you can.  For trouble shooting, there's no other way to start.
2. Your code appears to open a database object named `dbs`.  Leaving an object open is a classic misuse of system resources.  See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1653224.aspx/1).
3. Are you linking to external data, for example using `ODBC'?  Do some research to make sure that isn't creating the problem.
4. Make sure your database is in a "trusted location".  See [here](http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html#Configuration) for information.

You didn't mention if this report worked in the past... if it did, *what changed?*

Comment: The report works fine if I use a small number of sub-reports.

However, we have pretty much decided to ditch the idea of using the built-in tools to create this report and are studying Crystal Reports 2011 instead. It just seems like what I am trying to do is simply too much for access to handle.

Comment: I did. We are not linking to any outside DB and we have cleaned up all the code, and set the location as trusted, even tried running it on a local machine. We also switched from using any DLookups to ELookups and we get the exact same result every time.

Comment: I doubt Crystal Reports is the solution.  Access reports are perfectly adequate for Access data.  I think learning good techniques for Access is a better use of your time.  `DLookup()` is likely to be part of your problem -- it's not efficient.  If you're stuck on `DLookup()`, it just indicates improving Access today is going to be easier than improving Crystal Reports tomorrow.

Comment: Like I said, we are no longer using Dlookup, We are using ELookup, and so far, Crystal Reports has been a much easier tool... I am unsure why I should not bother with it when I have had so many issues with Access' built-in tools.

Comment: Oh, well, if the report runs on CR then you're set.  You didn't say that before.  Well done, and I hope it keeps going well.

Comment: I mean, I don't mind using Access, and Crystal Reports is not cheap, but I got the trial version and have seemed to have found better success so far with it working as it is supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `ELookup()` - I didn't know about that.

Comment: Allen Browne developed it. Glad I could help somehow.